# add/ remove div as the count of the number field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a set of number fields. Whatever number is inside the field I would like the same amount of div's displayed. When you add a number to the number field, another div should appear. when a number is subtracted from the number field, the div should disappear.

here are my notes- the change is set as an alert for testing purposes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.product-quantity').on('change',function(){
    alert('One of these is changed ' + $(this).attr('data-size'));

    // Using the attributes of $(this), create selector to find input fields with this  
   size, belonging to this product
// If the count of those fields is > than the value we have of this, then we remove
// If it's < than, we add fields
// If it's equal, we do nothing
// we add/remove based on this dymanic selector

});
});
```

Comment: It seems to me that if you have notes of what you want, you should be able to achieve those results.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: did any of these was useful to you?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/XyXTX/2/) is what you need. Have a look.
Note: after you change the a value in the box. you need to click outside the input to let the changes made.

for your html:

```
<input class="product-quantity" />
<div id="small-field-set" style='width:100%;min-height:100px;border:1px solid red;'></div>
```

for your javascript/jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.product-quantity').on('change', function () {
        $('#small-field-set').html('')
        var number = $('.product-quantity').val();
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            $('#small-field-set').append('<div style="min-height:10px;border:1px solid blue;">test' + (i + 1) + '</div>')
        }

    });
});
```

let number be the number/value that is inserted into the input.
Edited: I have added the remove the line whenever the value changes.

Comment: that looks good, but this just adds them and does not remove them

Comment: There you go, remove the old divs and added new divs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about changing a number, whenever you clear the input it will be considered a change, I added a button so you can trigger the change after the input.

Consider the following html:

```
<input id="product-quantity" value="0" />
<button id="change"> Change </button>
<div id="divParent"></div>
```

This code will add divs without deleting the ones that are already there, it will only cleaer the div if your input is less than the divs that are alreay written

```
$('#change').on('click', function () {

    var input = $('#product-quantity').val() || 0;
    var children=$('#divParent > div').size() || 0;     

    if(input < children){
        $('#divParent').empty();
        children=0;
    }

    for (var i = children+1; i <= input; i++) {
        $('#divParent').append(
        $('<div/>')
            .attr("id", "newDiv" + i)
            .text("hello world " + i));
    }


});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rvaldez/Lnaqf/), hope you find this useful.